# Problemas al ejecutar el emulador en android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Resulta que tengo el siguiente problema.

Al iniciar un emulador en **android_studio** este me manda la siguiente alerta:

> Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. VT is disable in BIOS.
>
> enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings (refer to documentation for
>   your computer)

ayuda porfas

Answer (score 0):

Este problema se presenta porque debes activar la virtualización desde BIOS, para solucionarlo:

1. Reinicia tu computador.
2. Entra al menú de BIOS presiona la tecla Supr, la tecla F1 o las teclas Alt y F4 dependiendo de tu sistema.
3. Activa la virtualización.
4. Guardar y Salir.

[image: BIOS Virtualización]

Aquí está una imagen donde se muestra como se vería el menú de la BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que ir al SDk Manager y ahi en la pestaña del medio SDK TOOLS en el ultimo dice  Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) ese tenes que instalar. si no te deja proba actualizar Android Emulator a la version 29.3.2.
si todo esto no te funciona entra a la bios como dice la otra respuesta y volve a probar lo que te digo.
[image: SDK Tools]